# Regex multi word boundry (exact word)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a way to match the exact words entered in Regex.

Unfortunately, boundary won't work because the search term can have multiple words.

I came up with this regex `(?:^|[\\s])(<word>)(?:$|[\\s!?])` and it works perfectly until there are multiple `<word>`s one to another.

### Example:

**Regex:** `(?:^|[\\s])(won)(?:$|[\\s!?])`

**Text:**

```
We won won won
```

In this text, it will only match every second word. I get this is because of requires a space but that space is already included with the previous word.

There are more difficulties with this.

It shouldn't match contractions, such as `won` shouldn't match `won't`. This also applies for hyphenated words `won-me`.

To make this simple I made unit tests for testing all the cases:

https://regex101.com/r/9Mj0UC/4/tests

*Note: I can't test in unit tests if it matches every single one or every second one. Therefore please simple look at test string panel.*

Can someone provide a solution for this Regex madness?

**It needs to be written in Regex (and JS compatible)**

Comment: Do you have a list of positive / negative examples?

Comment: What do you want to match in `We won won won`?

Comment: I want to match every `won` not only `We< won >won< won>`. Because with my regex it wont match the middle one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this way (without lookbehind):

```js
/(?:^|(?!['-])[^]\b)won(?!\B|['-])/i
```

1. Start of the line or any symbol except ' or - before word boundary.
2. The word.
3. Lookahead assertion negating not word boundary or ' or -. (This one does not capture the spaces so repeated words are captured.)

Comment: As far as I can see this works great. Give me a bit more time to test it.

Comment: Or maybe we can simplify a bit:`/(?:^|[^'-]\b)won(?!\B|['-])/i`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following expression:

```
(\w+-)?won(?![-'])
```

Additionally, you need to check if the first group is empty programmatically, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/SuzKuT/1/).

For engines supporting lookbehinds (`Chrome` and the like), you could even use

```
(?<!\w-)won(?![-'])
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com as well**](https://regex101.com/r/SuzKuT/2/).

---

The first could be done in `JS` like so:

```js
let strings = ["I won't win", "won", "I won", "You won", "We won, finally", "Have we won?", "We won!", "We non-won match", "He won-me"];

let rx = /(\w+-)?won(?![-'])/
strings.forEach(function(item) {
    m = rx.exec(item);
    if ((m != null) && (typeof(m[1]) == 'undefined'))
        console.log(item);
});
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: @Toto: Well, that's not entirely true, see e.g. http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html for an example. As of Chrome 62 (V8), lookbehinds are indeed supported.

Comment: Yes but not with  all browsers.

Comment: @Toto: That's exactly why I wrote *For engines supporting lookbehinds (Chrome and the like)*

Comment: The browser support is really low

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `\b` to match a word boundary:

```js
console.log("We won won won no-won won-with-hyphen".match(/(?<!-)\b(won)\b(?!-)/g))
```

[Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/SermmA/1)

Comment: Why are you puting word boundary in lookaround?

Comment: You must've missed this line: _"It shouldn't match hyphened words like won shouldn't match won't"_

Comment: The problem with this is negative lookbehind. It is not supported in most browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I think your regex matches won in `won't`

Comment: @Thefourthbird It would match but that is not the problem, it can easily be fixed by ignoring `'` like this: `(?<!-|')\b(won)\b(?!-|')`.  The real problem is lookbehind and the browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Use positive lookbehind and positive lookahead for spaces. below is the regex.

```js
//check if there is are white spaces before and after the word

let regex = /(?<=\s)won(?=\s)/g;

console.log("We won won won't won no-won".match(regex));
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: @Toto added the code snippet. Please check.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Toto this is false, ES 2018 supports lookbehind so they are only available in browsers supporting ECMA2018 standard, and that means, only the latest versions of Chrome can handle them.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy: Sure but only for Chrome.

Comment: @SwaroopDeval: When I run the code snippet I get an error : `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",`